# AWS EKS ALB Controller migration from v1 to v2 is creating unhealthy target groups for load balancers. Controller logs show timeout errors on sgs

Tags: kubernetes, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-security-group

I migrated the ALB Controller on EKS from v1 to v2. Everything was working fine for 25 days when I migrated EKS version from 1.24 to 1.25. 1 day later, the load balancers had unhealthy target groups.

On checking the controller logs, I got these errors:

```
{"level":"error","ts":"2023-10-04T09:48:04Z","msg":"Reconciler error","controller":"ingress","object":{"name":"frontend-ingress","namespace":"frontend"},"namespace":"frontend","name":"frontend-ingress","reconcileID":"43f32479-9248-47c0-b467-01d7694ca2ed","error":"failed to delete securityGroup: timed out waiting for the condition"}
```

[image: ALB Controller Logs]

I tried deleting the ingresses, but that was timing out too. So I checked the IAMPolicy and made a few changes regarding security groups and target groups. The current IAMPolicy is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcPeeringConnections",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:GetCoipPoolUsage",
                "ec2:DescribeCoipPools",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListeners",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeSSLPolicies",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeRules",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient",
                "acm:ListCertificates",
                "acm:DescribeCertificate",
                "iam:ListServerCertificates",
                "iam:GetServerCertificate",
                "waf-regional:GetWebACL",
                "waf-regional:GetWebACLForResource",
                "waf-regional:AssociateWebACL",
                "waf-regional:DisassociateWebACL",
                "wafv2:GetWebACL",
                "wafv2:GetWebACLForResource",
                "wafv2:AssociateWebACL",
                "wafv2:DisassociateWebACL",
                "shield:GetSubscriptionState",
                "shield:DescribeProtection",
                "shield:CreateProtection",
                "shield:DeleteProtection"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": "CreateSecurityGroup"
                },
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "true",
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateTargetGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateRule",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteRule"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/net/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/app/*/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "true",
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/net/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/app/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener-rule/net/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener-rule/app/*/*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetIpAddressType",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSecurityGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSubnets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroup",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteTargetGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/net/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/app/*/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "elasticloadbalancing:CreateAction": [
                        "CreateTargetGroup",
                        "CreateLoadBalancer"
                    ]
                },
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetWebAcl",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyRule"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/ingress.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteTargetGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/net/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/app/*/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/ingress.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The next step was to uninstall the controller and re-install it. We did that 2 times. The funny thing is, only 2/9 ingress files create good load balancers with healthy target groups. The rest ingress files create load balancers with unhealthy target groups.

There is an issue coming with security groups that causes target groups to be unhealthy at the ports.. The ALB controller still gives the 'timed out' error on deleting the security groups.

**Good Load Balancer**
Security Groups
[image: Load Balancer Security Group]

Target Group
[image: Target Group]

**Error Load Balancer**
Security Groups
[image: Load Balancer Security Group]

Target Group
[image: Target Group - Unhealthy]

I am not being able to figure out what to do, and what to check in order to rectify this issue. The services are working fine but just not accessible to the load balancers via the nodes.

I tried re-installing the ALB controller -

1. Deleted the IAM Service Accounts and re-created them
2. I attached the IAM Policy from - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.5.4/docs/install/iam_policy.json
3. I uninstalled ALB Controller and re-installed it using helm
4. I manually removed the leftover ingress files via patch command as the delete was timing out for hours

I expected, with the re-installation of the controller, things would be normal again. But that has not happened yet and nor does it look like a simple uninstallation and reinstallation will fix this.